# Disabling functionalities through GPO for Microsoft teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

Can We disable all the Icons on Teams page except the Chat option, I.e.., activities, calls, etc.,,

I may need this GPO for an organization Who can access only Chat functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an admin, you can use app setup policies to customize Microsoft Teams to highlight the apps that are most important for your users.

Please take a look at [Manage app setup policies in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/teams-app-setup-policies) and [Manage app permission policies in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/MicrosoftTeams/teams-app-permission-policies) documentation.

Comment: can one turn off all the "out of the box" items on the left menu like this though? I thought this could only add/block actual apps?